# Bind visible to whether field (in kendo observable) has changed or not?

Tags: kendo-ui

I would like to show or hide elements of my kendo template based on whether or not a field in my model has changed or not.

First attempt:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: schedulerEventFieldOne"/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: schedulerEventFieldTwo, visible: schedulerEventFieldOne.dirty"/>
```

Attempt two is to have a 'schedulerEventFieldOneOrigValue' field added to my model, then doing this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: schedulerEventFieldOne"/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: schedulerEventFieldTwo, visible: schedulerEventFieldOne != schedulerEventFieldOneOrigValue"/>
```

But this gives me an error stating that schedulerEventFieldOne is not defined. It seems that it doesn't like the equality test. Which is odd since, using a < o r > test seems to work fine: "visible: schedulerEventFieldOne > 0"

Is there a way to accomplish my task using the kendo binding? Or will I have to resort to jQuery again?

Answer (score 0):

You do not state any concern, so why dont you do it on the view model with the second approach? It's possible to do this i believe :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vm = kendo.observable({
    form: {
      country: ""
    },
    original: {
      country: ""
    },
    isDisabled: function() {
      return this.get("form.country") != this.get("original.country");
    },
    save: function() {

    }
  })

  kendo.bind($("#test"), vm);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: form.country" />
    <button data-bind="click:save, visible:isDisabled">Save</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```